# Get youtube or Vimeo video Id from Video link

Tags: c#, youtube, vimeo

Vimeo share video link looks like:

http://vimeo.com/89491724

YouTube share video link looks like:

http://youtu.be/GioRM0kU5m0

I want people to enter this into my website and I'll embed it using their embed code and just replacing the last (id) part with their values (that gets stored in a DB).

I can parse these out by taking the last values after the last slash "/". I can tell what site they are from based on if "vimeo" is in the string. My question is, am I opening myself up to any security issues by doing this? Is there anything a person could do to exploit this system that anyone can think of?

Are there any libraries out there for validation that maybe I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have a same problem few months ago and I have made this function to get video id for youtube and Vimeo..

Here is your Solution..

```
function Getvideoid(videolink)

var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var match = videolink.match(regExp);

  if (match && match[7].length == 11) 
    {
      alert("youtube video id : "+ match[7]);      
      return;
    }
    regExp = "vimeo\\.com/(?:.*#|.*/videos/)?([0-9]+)";
    match = videolink.match(regExp);
    if(match)
      {
       var videoid = videolink.split('/')[videolink.split('/').length - 1];
        alert("vimeo video id :"+videoid);
      }

 else 
  {
    alert("Unknown url");
  }
```

and **here is JSBIN Link**
http://jsbin.com/zoxicoko/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseVideo(url) {
    // - Supported YouTube URL formats:
    //   - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My2FRPA3Gf8
    //   - http://youtu.be/My2FRPA3Gf8
    //   - https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/My2FRPA3Gf8
    // - Supported Vimeo URL formats:
    //   - http://vimeo.com/25451551
    //   - http://player.vimeo.com/video/25451551
    // - Also supports relative URLs:
    //   - //player.vimeo.com/video/25451551

    url.match(/(http:|https:|)\/\/(player.|www.)?(vimeo\.com|youtu(be\.com|\.be|be\.googleapis\.com))\/(video\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/);

    if (RegExp.$3.indexOf('youtu') > -1) {
        var type = 'youtube';
    } else if (RegExp.$3.indexOf('vimeo') > -1) {
        var type = 'vimeo';
    }

    return {
        type: type,
        id: RegExp.$6
    };
}
```